# Sentinel-2 GCS subscription not producing any outputs

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, sentinel2

I am not sure if others have been able to get the Sentinel-2 GCS Pub/Sub subscription (*projects/gcp-public-data---sentinel-2/topics/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2*) to work in their applications/workflows, but every time I initialize a subscription for this bucket I am unable to receive any messages (note the blue line [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCIOJ.jpg) in the graph, which is consistent with other graphs of subscriptions I've made in the past). Does anyone have any suggestions for receiving notifications that a new image has been uploaded to the S2 GCS bucket?

Comment: Could you clarify where the topic `projects/gcp-public-data---sentinel-2/topics/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2` comes from? Is this a publicly available topic that has GCS notifications attached or did you create the topic and add notifications to it as described in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes#prereqs?

Comment: Hi! This is a public topic, provided to me by a Google Developer.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation for it?

Comment: That's the weird thing; when I attempt to look it up, I can't find any reference to it. Here is what was said in the original email correspondence I received from the Google Developer:
"We update the BigQuery (I had initially asked a question about BigQuery) tables daily with metadata, but you can also subscribe to the Pub/Sub topic for the data stored in GCS: 
projects/gcp-public-data---sentinel-2/topics/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2"

While this one doesn't produce any results, a similar pub/sub topic works for Landsat (included below).

Comment: "projects/gcp-public-data---landsat/topics/gcp-public-data-landsat"

Comment: I see, I would reach out to this developer and if needed, ask them to contact Cloud Pub/Sub dev team internally. Perhaps there is an issue with Sentinel2 subscription and they're just not aware of it.

Comment: Thank you Samarth, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I reached out to a Google Developer and the subscription is now working; there was an issue with the sub on their end. How do I close this question?